# Hide duplicate cells in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to hide duplicate cells in the same column with SQL.

My query is:

```
select invoice_number, position, article_number, quantity 
from orderpos
```

It returns the following:

[image]

I would like it to return:

[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN position = 1
            THEN invoice_number
            ELSE ''
            END invoice_number, 
       position, 
       article_number, 
       quantity 
FROM orderpos
ORDER BY invoice_number, 
         position
```

Comment: Thank you so much Akina for answering me

Comment: @Hajar, you should mark it as a solution if it did solve your problem.